# Erro "format specifies type", linguagem C

Tags: c

Tenho o seguinte código em C:

```
struct crPlayList{char music[120], singer[120];float mustime;struct crPlayList *next;};

struct crPlayList *start, *end, *aux;
```

Tenho uma função para busca de música:

```
void seacrPlayList(){
aux = start;
// restante do código
```

Linha da situação:

```
scanf("%s", aux);
```

Me retornando a seguinte mensagem:

> warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the
>         argument has type 'struct crPlayList *' [-Wformat]
>                   scanf("%s", aux);

E, quando faço a busca de uma música que inseri através pela função responsável, não é encontrado nada. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Mas a ideia desse `scanf` era ler os dados da música ? Se sim quais (uma vez que existem vários)? Mas fundamentalmente o problema é que não pode ler um `struct crPlayList` com `scanf("%s")`.

Comment: 1- A ideia era fazer uma pesquisa pelo nome e então listar os correspondentes. 2 - Como posso ler então? Ou não há uma maneira de ler da posição em si?

Comment: `scanf` lê da consola, logo você está a introduzir uma nova musica suponho eu. Nesse `scanf` que tem o warning você queria ler os 3 campos da estrutura ? para criar uma nova musica ? Ou esse `scanf` é para ler um nome de uma musica para fazer a pesquisa ? Mediante o que você está a tentar fazer assim a solução difere.

Comment: O `scanf` é para ler o que foi digitado, e, em cima disso, procurar no campo `music`. Tenho um laço while, que quando encontra correspondentes, printa na tela.

Comment: `while (aux != NULL){
   if (music == aux->music){
    printf("\nMusica  %s encontrada!\n\n", aux->music);
    printf("musica: %s", aux->music);
    printf("cantor: %s\n\n", aux->singer);
    return;
   }else{
    aux = aux->next;
   }
  }`

Comment: Então se esse `scanf` é para ler o nome de uma musica é so trocar o tipo do `aux` para um `char aux[120]` por exemplo.

Comment: Mudei meu código. Percebi que havia criado uma váriavel para armazenar, ams não estava usando: `char busc[120];
  printf("\nDigite o nome da música:");
  scanf("%s", busc);
  
  while (aux != NULL){
   if (busc == aux->music){
    printf("\nMúsica  %s encontrada:\n\n", aux->music);
    printf("Música: %s", aux->music);
    printf("Cantor: %s\n\n", aux->singer);
        printf("Duração: %f\n\n", aux->mustime);
    return;
   }else{
    aux = aux->next;
   }
  }`. Não me retorna mais a mensagem, porém ele roda e não encontra registro pelo nome. Lembrando, há um `aux = start;` antes

Comment: Isso já certamente será outro problema que não o que tem na pergunta, e que só será possivel de responder vendo bastante mais código do programa. Aconselho a abrir outra pergunta em relação a esse novo problema. Eu respondo aqui a esta para a fechar e ter uma solução aqui postada

Comment: Ok. vou abrir uma nova pergunta, e comento o link da mesma aqui

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/381252/while-não-encontra-correspondecia-linguagem-c

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe Sim é verdade, já tirei a tag `cmd`

Comment: Show de bola tchê!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O aviso indica-lhe que o formatador de leitura é `char*` que provem do `%s`, mas o local onde está a guardar o valor é um `struct crPlayList *`, logo ele não irá funcionar como espera pois são tipos completamente diferentes e irá resultar em **comportamento indefinido**.

```
struct crPlayList *aux;
scanf("%s", aux);
//     |      |-----------> tem struct crPlayList *
//     |---> espera char*
```

Tem duas soluções, mas dependem um pouco do que pretende fazer.

Caso esteja a ler apenas um texto, como o nome da musica, para procurar na lista então deve transformar a variável de leitura num vetor de `char` (renomeei para `nomeProcura` por clareza):

```
char nomeProcura[120];
scanf("%s", nomeProcura);
```

Caso esteja a tentar ler os dados de uma música para inserir na lista, tem de ler cada campo individualmente e guardar no local correto:

```
struct crPlayList *novaMusica = malloc(sizeof(struct crPlayList));
printf("Insira o nome da nova musica\n");
scanf("%s", novaMusica->music);
printf("Insira o cantor da nova musica\n");
scanf("%s", novaMusica->singer);
printf("Insira a duração da nova musica\n");
scanf("%s", &(novaMusica->mustime));
novaMusica->next = NULL;
```